# Removing posts and comments from Wordpress

Tags: admin-menu

I am using a plugin which creates both a custom post type for all my "posts" data and also another plugin which entirely handles the commenting system. Therefore I would like to entirely hide the comments and posts section from the site.

I currently have the following function:

```
function remove_admin_menus() {
        remove_menu_page( 'edit-comments.php' );
        remove_menu_page( 'edit.php' );
    }
```

However this doesn't seem to do anything. Do I need to call this function anywhere to make it actually remove the menu items?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to "hook" it to an action, in this case `admin_menu`:

```
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'remove_admin_menus' );
```

Just place it right after the function.